Communication complexity of $\text{DISJ}_n$ function
I have encountered this question when reading Razborov's communication complexity survey.

The function $\text{DISJ}_n$ is defined on $\{0, 1\}^n\times \{0, 1\}^n$
as $$\text{DISJ}_n(x, y) = 1 \iff \forall i\le n : x_i = 0\lor y_i = 0\;,$$
that is, the sets of positions where the strings $x$ and $y$ have a $1$ are disjoint.
Prove that $C(\text{DISJ}_n)\ge \Omega(n)$.


Hint. How many points $(x, y)$ with $\text{DISJ}_n(x, y) = 1$ do we have? And what
is the maximal size of a 1-rectangle?

Where $C(\text{DISJ}_n)$ is communication complexity of $\text{DISJ}_n$ function.
It is easy to know that there are $3^n$ points with $\text{DISJ}_n(x,y)=1$. The final thing is finding the maximal size of a 1-rectangle, i.e., the set of points have same transcript s.t. $\text{DISJ}_n(x,y)=1$.
I guess that size is $2^{n+n/2}$. However, all thing I can do to prove a contradiction is limited.
My try:
Assume that the maximal size of 1-rectangle is more than $2^{n+n/2}$. According to Dirichlet's principle, there are more than $2^{n/2}$ points $(x,y)$ have same $x$ part, say $x'$. Similarly, there are more than $2^{n/2}$ points $(x,y)$ have same $y$ part, say $y'$.
There must be two strings $z_1,z_2$ have same first $n/2$ bits s.t. $(x',z_1)$ and $(z_2,y')$ in the same 1-rectangle, so do $(z_2,z_1)$. Thus, the first $n/2$ bits of $z_1,z_2$ must be $0^{n/2}$.
Now I'm getting stuck since I cannot infer any further contradiction. Could you please help me continue proving? Thanks in advance!!
